# Measuring Read/Write Speed and Accessing Registers of a UFS Memory on an Embedded System

Tags: memory, qualcomm, ufs

I want to test the read and write speed of a UFS memory on a device with a Qualcomm processor. I am looking for a tool that can measure the speed of the UFS memory. The Software Version is QNX7.1.

Additionally, I want to read some registers in that storage. That should work with JTAG i guess?

I would appreciate recommendations for suitable tools or methods as well as instructions on how to use these tools.

I only know JTAG i can use to read some registers, but not the performance.